# How to load php files via $_GET variable OOP way

Tags: php, oop

I'm learning OOP in PHP.

I used to load in pages with the following logic:

```
// Example url: index.php?page=something

$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : false;

if (!empty($page)) {
    include 'content/' . $page . '.php';
}
```

But I'm wondering how it is done the object oriented way. Is it done by a method?

**Maybe something like this:**

```
public function loadContent($_GET['page'])
{
     $url = 'content/' . $_GET['page'] . '.php';

     return $url;
}
```

Comment: You have to invoke the function using the class object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this...

```
class Page {

    /**
     * The page name
     * 
     * @var string
     */
    private $page;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * 
     * @param string $page
     */
    public function __construct($page)
    {
        $this->page = $page;
    }

    /**
     * Load the content of the page
     * 
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function loadContent()
    {
        $file = 'content/' . $this->page . '.php';

        if (file_exists($file)) {
            return include $file;
        }
    }
}

// Load the page class if we have a page
if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
    $page = new Page($_GET['page']);
    echo $page->loadContent();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for directing me on the right track. I wasn't sure if such things also belonged in methods. Next up handling multiple parameters. Thanks again!